# Rails ACL plugin that works with devise/warden?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

As title, warden is very pluggable, I wonder if there is anything works with warden/devise?

Answer (score 4):

I use http://github.com/ryanb/cancan with Devise, its great and requires very little setup, you only have to define the abilitys as CanCan defaults to using current_user for the logged in user, which devise provides.

Answer (score 1):

I've also used [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)  with Devise. It requires very easy to setup and all your authorization logic resides in a single file, in that way its very modularized.

Answer (score 1):

I used acl9 with Devise. https://github.com/be9/acl9

I needed to dynamically grant authorization at the object level, which I don't think you can do with CanCan.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, which might be able to work alongside:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization